# How to pass asyncio event variable to non async callback function

Tags: python-asyncio

I recently have been trying to set event from non async callback and till it set one of my asyncio task is waiting. problem is I am unable to pass asincio.Event variable to non-async callback.

I am getting bellow lookup error.

```
    temp_thing = thing_var.get()
LookupError: <ContextVar name='thing' at 0x7f9ec00bd0>
```

for making "asyncio.Event" available out of asyncio.run loop. I have used "ContextVar". this was supposed to make my "asyncio.Event" global and hence available for callback to set it. I can print "ContexVar" name mean "ContexVar" is reaching to callback but for some reason it is not passing the "asyncio.Event".

here bellow is relevant code extract.

```
import asyncio
from contextvars import ContextVar
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.LoRaArgumentParser import LoRaArgumentParser
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD

class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):

    server_status = False

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    
    # on receive callback
    def on_rx_done(self):
        print("LoRa RxDone")    
        print(f"thing event name: {thing_var.name}")
        temp_thing = thing_var.get()
        print("tried to send event thing ...")
        temp_thing.set()

        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
    
# setup lora releted configs
def lora_config_setup():
    parser = LoRaArgumentParser("Continous LoRa receiver.")
    lora = LoRaRcvCont(verbose=False)
    args = parser.parse_args(lora)  # lora sanity check

    assert (lora.get_agc_auto_on() == 1)

    lora.reset_ptr_rx()
    lora.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)

    return lora

async def superloop():
    # main super loop
    thing = asyncio.Event()
    thing_var.set(thing)

    print("asyncio loop starts ...")
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.create_task(task_1(thing)),
    )

async def task_1(thing):
    count = 0

    while True:
        # acquire the lock to protect the critical section

        print("waiting for thing")
        await thing.wait()

        print("task1: got event thing set")
        count = count + 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        print("task 1: reset event thing set")
        thing.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # from here code execution starts
    print('code execution started')
    thing_var = ContextVar('thing')

    BOARD.setup()
    lora = lora_config_setup()

    print("\nasync superloop code running")
    asyncio.run(superloop())

    print("code finished")
```

again output of this code when event callback function executed is as bellow.

```
code execution started

async superloop code running
asyncio loop starts ...
waiting for thing
LoRa RxDone
thing event name: thing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/sisig/git_repo_2/nurster-gateway/SX127x/LoRa.py", line 158, in _dio0
    self.on_rx_done()
  File "/home/pi/sisig/git_repo_2/nurster-gateway/pytest3.py", line 86, in on_rx_done
    temp_thing = thing_var.get()
LookupError: <ContextVar name='thing' at 0x7f9ec00bd0>
```

so if possible do provide info how I should use "ContexVar" or some other methode to pass event to "on_rx_done" event callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ContextVar seems to be exactly the wrong tool for what you are trying to do.  You say you have used it to create a global variable, but that is not what it is for.

You don't need to create a global variable at all.  I've re-arranged your code a little bit to create an Event object right at the beginning of superloop.  I pass it to the `LoRaRcvCont` constructor (through the lora_config_setup method).  I also pass it to task_1.  That's all you have to do.  No global variable necessary.

I didn't change your code except for the necessary changes, with one exception: I replaced your call to `asyncio.gather` with a simple await expression.  Gathering the result from one task, although it works, seems to me like poor style.

I could not, of course, run this program so my apologies for any stupid mistakes.  But I hope you get the idea.

```
import asyncio
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.LoRaArgumentParser import LoRaArgumentParser
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD

class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):

    server_status = False

    def __init__(self, event, verbose=False):  # changed
        self.event = event  # changed
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)

    
    # on receive callback
    def on_rx_done(self):
        print("LoRa RxDone")    
        print(f"thing event name: {thing_var.name}")
        self.event.set()  # changed
        print("tried to send event thing ...")
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
    
# setup lora releted configs
def lora_config_setup(event):  # changed
    parser = LoRaArgumentParser("Continous LoRa receiver.")
    lora = LoRaRcvCont(event, verbose=False)  # changed
    args = parser.parse_args(lora)  # lora sanity check

    assert (lora.get_agc_auto_on() == 1)

    lora.reset_ptr_rx()
    lora.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)

    return lora

async def superloop():
    # main super loop
    ev = asyncio.Event()           # changed
    lora = lora_config_setup(ev)   # changed

    print("asyncio loop starts ...")
    await task_1(ev)  # changed
    # removed call to gather

async def task_1(event):   # changed thing to event
    count = 0

    while True:
        # acquire the lock to protect the critical section

        print("waiting for thing")
        await event.wait()

        print("task1: got event thing set")
        count = count + 1
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        print("task 1: reset event thing set")
        event.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # from here code execution starts
    print('code execution started')

    BOARD.setup()

    print("\nasync superloop code running")
    asyncio.run(superloop())

    print("code finished")
```

I suspect that this might not solve your real problem.  Does the callback to `on_rx_done` occur in the main thread?  If not, you need to (1) save the main event loop in the LoRaRcvCont constructor, and (2) set the Event flag using the cross-threaded asyncio method `self.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(self.event.set)`.  Let me know if you need me to describe this further.

Comment: thanks paul for answering my question, after posting this question 1. I hade found out later on that "class asyncio.Event - An event object. Not thread-safe."  2.  rx_done is rpi gpio event which calls from main thread. 3. asyncio run always creates new thread. I have also tried your suggestions of saving "loop" and "call_soon _hreadsafe". that helped alot after adding thead_queue I was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

this might not be most elegant way to resolve this issue but this is working snippet from my project is this. also thanks @paul for suggestion it haleped a lot.

1. saved context as paul suggested
2. thread safe call to async task from on_rx_done as paul suggested
3. added threaded queue which I might have added in on_rx_done call directly but instead added in "async rx_payload_task".
4. task put in "rx_payload_task" is used in "make_json_string" task which start my code producer consumer tasks chain to communicate with server.

```
from contextvars import ContextVar
import asyncio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from SX127x.LoRa import *
from SX127x.LoRaArgumentParser import LoRaArgumentParser
from SX127x.board_config import BOARD
from queue import Empty, Queue

class LoRaRcvCont(LoRa):

    server_status = False

    def __init__(self, verbose=False):
        super(LoRaRcvCont, self).__init__(verbose)
        self.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)
        self.set_dio_mapping([0] * 6)
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()  # saved context loop as paulus suggested
   
    # on receive callback
    def on_rx_done(self):
        print("LoRa RxDone")
        rx_task = self.rx_payload_task()
        # execute a coroutine
        future = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(rx_task, self.loop) # sart new task in saved loop
        # wait for the task to finish
        future.result()

        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        self.clear_irq_flags(RxDone=1)
        print("on_rx_done task finish")

    async def rx_payload_task(self):
        # this task is wraper for sync async code from here I call all async code

        #print("rx_payload_task started")
        payload = self.read_payload(nocheck=True)

        # print prased and actual payload
        print(payload)

        # do some operation
        # add task in lora_to_gateway_queue if payload not empty
        if len(payload) > 2:  # uncomment in case of async code
            try:
                print('lora_to_gateway_queue put task, start')
                # await temp_lora_to_gateway_queue.put(payload)
                lora_rx_queue.put(payload)
                print('lora_to_gateway_queue put task,  done')
            except:  # pylint: disable=bare-except
                print('ERROR in put lora_to_gateway_queue.')
                
        print("rx_payload_task finish")

        # make json string request from lora event string
    async def make_json_string(self, lora_to_gateway_queue):
        print("make_json_string task started")
        # print(f"current loop is: {asyncio.get_running_loop()}")
        while True:
            # get an item from the queue without blocking
            try:
                payload = lora_rx_queue.get_nowait()
            except Empty:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                # print("make_json_string empty queue")
                continue
            else:
                print('data recived from lora queue: ')
                print(payload)

            # Notify the queue that the "work item" has been processed.
            # lora_to_gateway_queue.task_done()
            lora_rx_queue.task_done()
            # print("lora_to_gateway_queue put done")

    async def start(self):
        self.reset_ptr_rx()
        self.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)
        count = 0
        while True:

            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            count = count + 1
            print("loop" + str(count))

# setup lora releted configs
def lora_config_setup():
    parser = LoRaArgumentParser("Continous LoRa receiver.")
    lora = LoRaRcvCont(verbose=False)
    args = parser.parse_args(lora)  # lora sanity check

    lora.set_mode(MODE.STDBY)
    lora.set_freq(433)  # Set the frequency to 433 MHz
    lora.set_pa_config(pa_select=1)
    lora.set_rx_crc(False)
    # lora.set_coding_rate(CODING_RATE.CR4_6)
    # lora.set_pa_config(max_power=20, output_power=20)
    # lora.set_lna_gain(GAIN.G1)
    # lora.set_implicit_header_mode(False)
    lora.set_low_data_rate_optim(False)
    # lora.set_pa_ramp(PA_RAMP.RAMP_50_us)
    # lora.set_agc_auto_on(True)
    assert (lora.get_agc_auto_on() == 1)

    print(lora)

    lora.reset_ptr_rx()
    lora.set_mode(MODE.RXCONT)

    return lora


async def main():
    #main async loop from here async tasks are created and executed

    # setup the board
    BOARD.setup()

    # setup the lora
    lora = lora_config_setup()

    # create the shared queue
    lora_to_gateway_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    try:
        print("asyncio loop main starts ...")
        await asyncio.gather(
            asyncio.create_task(lora.start()),
            asyncio.create_task(lora.make_json_string(
                lora_to_gateway_queue))
        )
        # )

        print("main done")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        sys.stderr.write("KeyboardInterrupt\n")
    finally:
        sys.stdout.flush()
        print("")
        lora.set_mode(MODE.SLEEP)

    print(lora)
    BOARD.teardown()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lora_to_gateway_queue_var = ContextVar('lora_to_gateway_queue')
    # WORKER_NUMBER = 1

    # create the thread safe (non async) queue
    lora_rx_queue = Queue()

    print("\nasync main code running")
    asyncio.run(main())

    print("code finished")
```